# Is MyViewController in the window hierarchy?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Is there a way to check if `MyViewController` is in the window hierarchy ?
I want to know if I can present an `UIAlertController` from it :

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hello", message: "Just for fun", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
MyViewController.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Every view controller on screen has to be on window hierarchy ? You could have an instance of the viewController present alert instead of the class, then you would know that view controller is active.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The view controller's `view` will have its `window` property set if its in the hierarchy

```
if MyViewController.view.window != nil {
    // In the window hierarchy
}
```

Comment: This solution does not work! I get that `controller.view.window` is not null, but this error still occurs `Attempt to present <UIViewController> on <UIAlertController> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`